# Rails Sort objects by sum of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Each of my users has an array of integers. The users attend a competition and I would like to sort them by the sum of the first 7 elements of their array. I know how to do each part individually, but I'm not sure how to put it together and display it in the show.

inside the `def show`

```
@competition.users.sort_by{|e| e.daily.first(7).sum}
for comp in @competition.users
  p comp.name
  p comp.daily #Their array
end
```

This is how I get the sum of the first 7 elements (currently used in my view):

```
user.daily.first(7).sum
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would sort the users in the descending order of their sum. User with highest sum will be in the top. Remove the `-` for ascending sort

```
@sorted_users = @competition.users.sort_by{|user| -user.daily.first(7).sum}
for comp in @sorted_users
  p comp.name
  p comp.daily #Their array
end
```

Or you can use `sort_by!` which will do inplace sorting

```
@competition.users.sort_by!{|user| -user.daily.first(7).sum}
for comp in @competition.users
  p comp.name
  p comp.daily #Their array
end
```

Comment: I have tried this on my test case, but it doesn't seem to take. Do I need to save it to the list? It doesn't change anything in the print statements or the view

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about the `!` Now to figure out what that does and why it matters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code was right but you didnt store sorted data anywhere

```
@competition.users.sort_by{|e| e.daily.first(7).sum}.each do |comp|
  p comp.name
  p comp.daily #Their array
end
```